# How to recognize when sunflower seed are ripe for harvesting?

Tags: seeds, harvesting, sunflowers

I want to save my sunflower seed, and not for food, but for reseeding in other areas.

Last year, I was too late: Birds ate everything, almost to the last piece of seed. This year I want to be faster. some of early sunflower specimens already have their flowers hanging and getting brown. But, how to recognize when sunflower seed are ripe for harvesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seeds will still ripen if you protect the flower head with a paper bag.

Alternatively, tie a few CDs loosely to the sunflower stalks so the wind moves them around. The flashing "rainbow colours" as the light refracts from them will deter most birds.

Comment: Sunflowers are 5m high, and putting paperbag on their flowers without damaging plant would be a serious challenge to me.